# Messages dropped in Syslog-NG - Buffer configuration?

Tags: syslog, syslog-ng

i'm using Syslog-NG 3.8 as a syslog server receiving messages from many different sources, about 400 servers (& filtering them and relaying to a splunk server eventually).

however, it looks like many messages are "dropped" even before they are filtered and forwarded to the splunk instance.

i have a configuration where i'm keeping track of "incoming" messages before filtering in a flat file and i can't see some messages in there (see example below), while i can see the tcp trace successfully when running a tcpdump, meaning that Syslog-NG "drops" messages during the "source" mecanism.

i suspect this is due to the large mount of messages incoming on its interface, and i need to do some tuning with buffers & specific options.

here is a concrete example of the bug :

from the source machine, if i do a little loop sending messages every second with an ID that increments (so 20,21,22,23,24 & so on) :

```
root@sm1u1050vmo /var/log: for ((i=20;i<100;i++)); do logger -p auth.notice "test auth notice $i" ; sleep 1 ; done
```

if i tail the "incoming.log" flat file on Syslog-NG (receiver), i can see many missing messages :

```
[root@xm1p1034vmo 20]# tail -f incoming.log | grep sm1u1050vmo
Sep 20 12:27:32 sm1u1050vmo root: [ID 702911 auth.notice] test auth notice 28
Sep 20 12:27:34 sm1u1050vmo root: [ID 702911 auth.notice] test auth notice 30
Sep 20 12:27:37 sm1u1050vmo root: [ID 702911 auth.notice] test auth notice 33
Sep 20 12:27:42 sm1u1050vmo root: [ID 702911 auth.notice] test auth notice 38
Sep 20 12:27:43 sm1u1050vmo root: [ID 702911 auth.notice] test auth notice 39
Sep 20 12:27:52 sm1u1050vmo root: [ID 702911 auth.notice] test auth notice 48
```

we can clearly see many messages missing.

here is a small part of my config, with options & sources :

```
options {
  chain_hostnames(no);
  log_msg_size(8192);
  time_reopen(2);
  create_dirs(yes);
  use_dns(yes);
  keep_hostname(yes);
  stats_freq(3600);
  flush_lines(1);
  log_fifo_size(1000);
};
```

the source being used :

```
source s_EXTERNAL {
         network(transport("udp") log-fetch-limit(500));
};
```

the "local copy" destination being used to track these incoming messages before they are filtered :

```
destination d_INCOMING_ALL       
{ 
 file("/app/syslog-ng/logs/${YEAR}/${MONTH}/${DAY}/incoming.log" create-dirs(yes)); 
};
```

note, i am currently trying to play with options such as **so-rcvbuf()** in the source (& adapting the kernel parameter *rmem_max* at the same time). it was 16Mb and i increased  it to 64M but it didn't change anything for now. i can still see **RcvbufErrors** & **packet receive errors** increasing when running a **netstat -us**

any hints please ?

thanks

Comment: a few things is not clear for me, while you sent those 100 message was there still other traffic ?
it would be nice to see how the source and destination is connected ? are you using flow-control ?
the log_fifo_size(1000) states that syslog-ng can hold 1000 at a time, based

Answer (score 0):

I'd tell you a UDP joke, but you probably wouldn't get it. Seriously, UDP is not guaranteed to arrive. Change the protocol to TCP on each end, and you should be set. Protocol aside, if your system is dropping messages at the rate of 1 per second, you likely have configuration issues on your network or it's simply overloaded.